# Azure, Download the site to a local development environment?

Tags: azure

This might not be so much of a programming question..but still.. 
I have the need of getting a site the currently is hosted in azure down to a local development environment.. is there anyway to do that?, any tools or such?..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you put it there?  Was the .cspkg first loaded to Windows Azure blob storage (prior to publishing in Windows Azure)?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently. Once the cloud service deployment package has been handed over to the Azure Fabric controller, there is no way to reclaim it, even if you submit a support ticket. The closest you can get to this is either upload packages to Windows Azure Blob Storage first, then deploy from there, or enable remote desktop and copy the files from inside the VM to an external storage account.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do one of the following:

- If you have RDP enabled, you can remote in and grab the files
- Otherwise, I would suggest creating a support case and having Microsoft help you get out the files: https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?&c1=501&gprid=14928&&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn